# How to specify params in a hash

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a Community Chef cookbook for installing JRuby. I am having trouble specifying a version of a Gem to be installed. I have literally tried every combination of hashes, keys, string, etc. that I can think of.

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
default[:jruby][:gems] = ["some-gem", "another-one"]
```

Yes, that is an array of strings, but an array of hashes should be possible.

This is read by the following snippet:

```
node[:jruby][:gems].each do |gem|
  Chef::Log.info "Installing Jruby Gem #{gem}"
  if gem.is_a? Hash
    name = gem.delete(:name)
  else
    name = gem
    gem = nil
  end
  jruby_gem name, gem || {}
end
```

And ends up in the hands of this definition:

```
define :jruby_gem, :source => nil, :version => nil do
  gem_package params[:name] do
    gem_binary "#{node[:jruby][:install_path]}/bin/gem"
    source params[:source] if params[:source]
    version params[:version] if params[:version]
  end
end
```

Given that code, what hash of hashes will fill the `:name` and `:version` values in the resulting definition?

Things I have tried are in the following realm...

```
[
  {:name => "some-gem", :version => "0.1.2"},
  {:name => "another-one"} # I don't need to constrain every Gem to a version
]
```

**Edit:**

So thanks for the totally correct Ruby-esque responses, but actually I did try the array of hashes approach in a few variations before turning to SO. Fatigue made me typo the structure that originally appeared in my question.

The problem I am seeing seems to concern Chef and the definition you see above. The error I get is as follows...

```
Node attributes are read-only when you do not specify which precedence level to set. To set an attribute use code like `node.default["key"] = "value"'

  Cookbook Trace:
  ---------------
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/jruby/recipes/default.rb:48:in `block in from_file'
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/jruby/recipes/default.rb:45:in `each'
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/jruby/recipes/default.rb:45:in `from_file'

  Relevant File Content:
  ----------------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/jruby/recipes/default.rb:

   41:    notifies :create_if_missing, "file[/etc/profile.d/jruby.sh]"
   42:  end
   43:
   44:  # install all gems defined in the module
   45:  node[:jruby][:gems].each do |gem|
   46:    Chef::Log.info "Installing Jruby Gem #{gem}"
   47:    if gem.is_a? Hash
   48>>     name = gem.delete(:name)
   49:    else
   50:      name = gem
   51:      gem = nil
   52:    end
   53:    jruby_gem name, gem || {}
   54:  end
   55:
```

Comment: `["some-gem", "another-one"]` is an array, not a hash...

Comment: That's a good point. It's a function of my being tired, not my being silly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the problem here is not your attributes but your actual cookbook.

The implementation of the jruby cookbook you (and I, today!) are using is not compatible with Chef 11+.  See this link:

https://www.chef.io/blog/2013/02/05/chef-11-in-depth-attributes-changes/

> Now you must specify which precedence level you want to write to when setting attributes; accessing attributes on the node directly is only for reading.

The line which is erroring here is doing exactly that:

```
if gem.is_a? Hash
  name = gem.delete(:name) <- This is modifying node.jruby.gems.some_gem!
```

If you want to use this, therefore, you have to do take one of a few approaches:

1. Fork the jruby cookbook and fix it.  It's incredibly old and none of the existing direct forks support Chef 11, so if you want to take it over you can become like unto a tiny god.
2. Do your gem installations using a separate cookbook entirely (this is what we have been doing up to this point).
3. Create a wrapper cookbook which includes the jruby cookbook *without* setting jruby.gems, and add an attribute and Ruby block of your own that sets things the 'right' way.

One example would be:

```
my_gems = node['jruby']['my_gems'].dup

my_gems.each do |gem|
  if gem.is_a? Hash
    name = gem.delete('name')
  else
    name = gem
    gem = nil
  end
  jruby_gem name, gem || {}
end
```

This will actually work, given the right amount of tweaking.  An example chef client output using this exact block would be:

```
> Recipe: mycompany-jruby::default 
> * gem_package[some-package] action install 
> - install version #.#.# of package some-package
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[
  {:name => "some-gem", :version => "0.1.2"},
  {:name => "another-one"} # I don't need to constrain every Gem to a version
]
```

Notice that the inner data structures are defined with curly braces, not square braces.

- `[]`'s make an Array
- `{}`'s make a Hash

You were creating an Array of Arrays, but what you really want is an Array of Hashes.

**EDIT**

The docs seem to indicate you could try something along the lines of:

```
default[:jruby].set[:gems] = ["some-gem", "another-one"]
```

This is what I got from a brief skim of:
https://www.chef.io/blog/2013/02/05/chef-11-in-depth-attributes-changes/

Comment: Yes, that's exactly as the code stood when I blearily typed up my question. For additional fun, see the actual error in my edited post.